# Variable substitution GeoWebCache

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

I have my Geoserver set up, I can pass variables in my WMS requests using:

```
env=value1:50;value2:100;
```

Now I want to send a reseed request - using the REST API - to GeoWebCache(GWC) and pass these variables aswell. I've tried passing them as a form field just like all other fields:

```
var seedForm = {
  format:'image/png',
  gridSetId:'EPSG:4326',
  maxX:7.230455,
  maxY:54.01786,
  minX:2.992192,
  minY:50.74753,
  parameter_STYLES:'tvt:choropleth',
  threadCount:16,
  type:'reseed',
  zoomStart:10,
  zoomStop:10,
  env:'value1:200;value2:300;'
}
```

However this is not working for me.

To sum up: everything is working in a regular WMS request. The reseed requests through GWC REST API are working aswell, only the variables do not get passed from GWC to GeoServer during tile seeding.